# CentOS boot problem

Tags: centos, vmware

We're using VMware Server which is running on CentOS in our company environment. As you can see,now the only thing holding this up is the CentOS can't boot. Also, I am guessing it sounds like a superblock corrupt. What might be the problem?

[image: sreenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of the screen shows the answer - `/dev/sda1` is missing, so the RAID device `/dev/md3` is invalid. There are two lines, the second telling you that `/dev/md3` is invalid.